# How to find out the index of a combo box item by name using WinAPI in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, combobox, delphi-2009

I have a Delphi application A, which needs to select a certain item in a combo box of another Delphi application B.

A knows the text of the combo box item to select.

In order to select the combo box item, application A needs to know the index of the item in the combo box.

How can I figure out the index of a combo box item, when I only know its text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SItem: string;
begin
  SItem := 'Beta';
  Caption := IntToStr(SendMessage(ComboBox1.Handle, CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT,
    -1, LPARAM(PChar(SItem))));
end;
```

(`uses CommCtrl`).

Comment: Can you tell me the value of the CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT constant? Or the unit, where it is defined.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko: It's in `Messages`. But for the record: `CB_FINDSTRINGEXACT       = $0158`

Comment: Instead of using `integer(@SItem[1])` you should cast to the correct type which is LPARAM: `LPARAM(PChar(SItem))`